# Error occured while calling profile image url from google play service api

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to get google plus profile image, using google play service api.
I used ImageManager.loadImage.

But I encounted error.
check [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59163).

this error fixed but i'm.

My code like this...

```
ImageManager im = ImageManager.create(getApplicationContext());                 
im.loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener(){
@Override
public void onImageLoaded(Uri uri, Drawable drawable){
    Log.i("TAG", "please....");
}}, getGamesClient().getCurrentPlayer().getIconImageUri());
```

My error report like this.

```
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageBroadcastReceiver: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2244)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1279)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4870)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager$b
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1165)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:4226)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(SourceFile:21)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2237)
12-18 20:38:07.505: E/AndroidRuntime(15150):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: thanks kara.
i really thank you for your teaching.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code in my project for the same

```
ImageView player1IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_player_1_fs);
    ImageView player2IV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_player_2_fs);
    TextView p1Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_player_1_fs);
    TextView p2Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_player_2_fs);

    ImageManager imageManager = ImageManager.create(getApplicationContext());
    if (mRoomId != null) {
        MyLog.printLog("mRoomId :" + mRoomId + getGamesClient().toString());
        for (Participant p : mParticipants) {
            String pid = p.getParticipantId();

            if (pid.equals(mMyId)) {
                MyLog.printLog("p.getIconImageUri()) :" + p.getIconImageUri());
                MyLog.printLog("p.getHiResImageUri() :" + p.getHiResImageUri());

                imageManager.loadImage(player1IV, p.getIconImageUri(), R.drawable.stub);
                p1Name.setText(p.getDisplayName());

                continue;
            } else {
                imageManager.loadImage(player2IV, p.getIconImageUri(), R.drawable.stub);
                p2Name.setText(p.getDisplayName());
            }
        }
    } else {
        // load image
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("pp/" + mRoboticPlayer.getName() + ".jpg");
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            player2IV.setImageDrawable(d);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            imageManager.loadImage(player2IV, R.drawable.stub);
        }
        p2Name.setText(mRoboticPlayer.getName());

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your help.
But I still have same problem.
my p.getIconImageUri value is "content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/33407107/22".
is this right?

Comment: I did solve this problem now. your code work very well. thanks Jatin

Comment: sorry Jatin Malwal. My reputation is so low.
How do i accept your answer?

Comment: you can accept it by just clicking on the left side right blank button.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a Proguard issue. The Google Play Games library is getting obfuscated, so it can't find the necessary classes at runtime. Try to set the target API level on your AndroidManifest.xml to 17 or above (this changes the behavior of Proguard) and see if this fixes the issue:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: @Bruno This feature doesn't work at all, please fix it. I know you work on Google games framework.